# Custom page template for content pages

Tags: theming

Is there any way to make a custom page.html.twig template in Drupal 8?

By default, Drupal generates some suggestions, but I'm looking for something like page--node--content-type.html.twig.

Comment: I think the question and especially the title is very confusing, but I think that's because you don't know the correct name for what you are asking. I'm not sure if you added the tag, but I guess it was @kiamlaluno: What you are searching for are theme hook suggestions, writing an answer now..

Answer (score 14):

You are looking for [hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/8).

HOOK is the name of the template, in your case, page. You should be able to add the following to your theme in the .theme file.

In there, do something like this:

```
function yourtheme_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    $suggestions[] = 'page__node__' . $node->getType();
  }
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry but didn't work.

Comment: i have found one solution (workaround) may be not the best but at list it works. if i add these lines "if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    $suggestions[] = $prefix . $delimiter . $node->getType();
  }" to core theme.inc file in 'theme_get_suggestions' than it will work and even generates comments on debug mode! how can i add to theme file to make it work.

Comment: I noticed that I didn't change HOOK to page in my example, if you didn't change that then that would explain why it didn't work. If you did, post your code, otherwise we can't help.

Comment: [`hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK/8) is not invoked for themes:

"This hook allows the module implementing hook_theme() for a theme hook to provide alternative theme function or template name suggestions. This hook is only invoked for the first module implementing hook_theme() for a theme hook."

Other than that, fantastic answer. I made the necessary edits.

Comment: @Cottser: You are half-correct :) It is not called for themes, correct (which IMHO is a bug, like a few other hooks that themes should be able to implement), but it is called for a all modules: https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/8.0.x/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Theme/ThemeManager.php#L231, thats a normal hook invocation, for all modules. So the documentation is wrong. But thanks for the edit!

Comment: @Berdir: Oh you're right, it's been too long. https://www.drupal.org/node/1751194#comment-7778323 I'll open an issue to fix the docs.

Comment: I missed the comment edit window :( docs issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/2430909

Comment: Worked for me, and I have to say that this function is called from my theme

Answer (score 6):

This code from Jeff Burnz (https://www.drupal.org/node/2521876#comment-10684366) solved it for me. It also places the suggestion above page--node so the capability to override with page--node--% and page--node--[id] remains.

```
<?php
function THEME_NAME_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  // Add content type suggestions.
  if ($node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node')) {
    array_splice($suggestions, 1, 0, 'page__' . $node->getType());
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: `\Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node')` and `\Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')` both return the node object, I'm not sure if one is quicker or more recommended than the other.

Comment: And heres the answer: https://www.drupal.org/node/2295317 reading the patch all requests for the node object were converted to routeMatch :)

Answer (score 3):

Your file name is bad, rename page.**htm**.twig to page.**html**.twig

After for clear your cache during page refresh, enable an use settings.local.php file inside your installation, on linux by example, copy and rename the example file to the good location with this command:

> cp /sites/example.settings.local.php /sites/default/settings.local.php

Uncomment this lines inside your settings.php :

```
 if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/settings.local.php')) {
     include __DIR__ . '/settings.local.php';
 }
```

And inside /sites/default/services.yml use this value:

```
debug: true
```

Inside settings.local.php, uncomment this line :

```
$settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';
```

Because Drupal say

> Do not use this setting until after the site is installed.

Now, your environment is ready, you can create theme and modules, but if you add a template file, you need to clear the cache manually :)

Note: don't use this configuration in production (bad performances for user/server).

Comment: The OP wants to use page--node--[content-type].html.twig instead of page.html-twig Drupal 8 uses.

Comment: Regarding the Twig settings in services.yml, `auto_reload` is already enabled when you enable `debug`, and I have yet to see any value in disabling the Twig cache. Disabling the Twig cache makes it harder to debug compiled templates and I have not seen any benefits so far in enabling it. I would say the vast majority of folks will do great by only enabling `debug`.

Answer (score 1):

it is ok ,according to [drupal 8 theme api](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!theme.api.php/group/themeable/8)  the template file for `page` is `page.html.twig`, may be you did not clear cache.

Comment: The OP wants to create a custom template file for a page basing on the content type of the node being shown. The question is not "Why isn't Drupal 8 using page.html.twig?"

Comment: drupal 8 default suggestions are:
* page--node--2.html.twig
* page--node--%.html.twig
* page--node.html.twig
* page.html.twig

but i would like to make custom page.html.twig for example page--node--article.html.twig where article is content(node) type name.

if i just add this file to my theme it won't work.
this page--node--article.html.twig or this page--article.html.twig doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

It's like:

- `node--[content-type].html.twig` ex: `node--article.html.twig`
- `node--[content-type]--[display-format].html.twig`, ex: `node--article--full.html.twig`

Here the screenshot of template suggestion:

[image]

Comment: it's not a page.html.twig template.

Comment: The question was about page templates.