# how to create template of user register, login and forget password in drupal 8?

Tags: theming, 8

How to create template of user register, login and forget password in drupal 8 can we create template same as we created earlier in drupal7 ?

I want to open these forms in popup on clicking links

Answer (score 7):

Yes it same as drupal 7.

For example:

We are using `page--user--register.tpl.php` for registration page template in D7. In D8 changed to twig extension `page--user--register.html.twig`.

You can enable debug mode in D8 so you can easily see the twig file need to use in your case. You can refer [Drupal 8 custom page template](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/141373/drupal-8-custom-page-template) to see how to enable debug mode.

[image]

Some links how to override the template files.

https://www.drupal.org/node/2521876

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/working-with-twig-templates

https://www.drupal.org/node/2668886

Comment: can we create template as user_login_form.html.twig except page--user--register.html.twig,if its possible so how to proceed

Comment: Yes you need to check how to add a custom template file for user registration.

Comment: do you have any link ?

Comment: This link give you an idea how to override a template https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/working-with-twig-templates

Comment: one more thing we use this code in drupal 7 for creating custom template 'user_login' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'templates/user-login',
    ),

Comment: what we have to modify for using same above code in drupal 8

Comment: I have not override creating custom template in drupal 8. I think you can ask a separate question for that. So you can get a help easily.

Answer (score 1):

for your case answer is  `page--user--register.html.twig`,
but generally, you can use below twig template naming suggestions:

```
page--user.html.twig
page--user--login.html.twig
page--user--password.html.twig
page--user--register.html.twig
```

I suggest you use `page--user.html.twig`, for all of these pages.